# Pygame rect=rect.inflate() vs rect.inflate_ip()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am new to python and pygame. Why should i assign the `inflate()` method to a new rect object as :

```
rectObj=rectObj.inflate()
```

while with `inflate_ip()` i don't need to assign it to any variables, but only calling the method actually does change the object:

```
rectObj.inflate_ip()
```

What are the differences, and i mean it more pythonic rather than pygamic (i know what `inflate` does).

Answer (score 1):

rectObj.inflate() returns another rectangle, so you are rebinding the name 'rectObj' to the new rectangle.

inflate_ip() does the same thing, but in place ('ip').  I would use the second, unless you want to create a different name for the inflated rectangle

see here, and notice what each method returns http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html